# What are the default values set to in a slice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have had a look at the top answers on [why-does-list-1-not-equal-listlenlist-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903407/why-does-list-1-not-equal-listlenlist-1) and [what-are-the-default-slice-indices-in-python-really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-in-python-really) to learn about what the default values are set to in a slice. Both of the top answers refer to the following documentation:

Given `s[i:j:k]`,

> If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k). Note, k cannot be zero. If k is None, it is treated like 1.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
s = "hello"
forward_s = s[::1]
print(forward_s) # => "hello"

backward_s = s[::-1]
print(backward_s) # => "olleh"
```

I know that if the indices are omitted then Python treats that as if the value of `None` was used in those places. According to the documentation the indices of `i` and `j` in `[i:j:k]` are set to "end" values depending on the sign of `k`. For a positive `k`, I'm assuming `i` is set to `0` and `j` is set to the length of the string. What are the values set for a negative `k` though?

For instance, the following also reverses the string:

```
reversed_str = s[-1:-6:-1]
```

So maybe the default value for `i` is set to `-1` and `j` is set to `-len(s) - 1` when `k = -1`?

Comment: that seems like the correct analysis. otherwise it would try to go from 0 to -1 to -2... so `[::-1]` would not properly reverse the list, but rather would give the first element and then the rest reversed.

Comment: What are "end values"?

Comment: When k is negative, i and j are treated as end values from the terminating end of the string. The docs, quoted in the answer you linked are explicit about that.

Comment: Okay well if `len(str) - 1` and `0` are the "end values" then why doesn't this work: `"hello"[len("hello") - 1: 0: -1]`? This returns "olle" instead of "olleh".

Comment: That's what I want to clarify. Whether `-1` and `-len(s) - 1` are the other set of end values, specifically for a negative value of k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) are `None`, `None`, and `None`.

```
class Sliceable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, slice):
        print(slice)

Sliceable()[::]
>>> slice(None, None, None)
```

This is regardless of the fact, that [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) does require a `stop` argument. The library documentation is a little bit less explicit on this, but the [C API makes clear](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_New), that all three values maybe empty:

> The `start`, `stop`, and `step` parameters are used as the values of the slice object attributes of the same names. Any of the values may be `NULL`, in which case the `None` will be used for the corresponding attribute.

**It's up to the sliceable object to make sense of the default values.** The convention is to use first element, past last element, minimal stepping as implemented by the builtin collections:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[slice(None, None, None])
>>> [1, 2, 3]
s[None:None:None])
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Negative stepping will cause the default `start` and `end` values to be reversed semantically, i.e.:

```
s = 'abc'
s[slice(None, None, -1)]
>>> 'cba'
s[::-1]
>>> 'cba'
```

Note that this does not mean a simple value flip, the default value of `end` is typically "*one past the end of the sequence, in whatever direction*", since `range()` is not inclusive for the end value, but the default values for a slice should include the full sequence.

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> `s[i:j:k]`
>
> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k` is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i, i+k, i+2*k, i+3*k` and so on, stopping when `j` is reached (but never including `j`). When `k` is positive, `i` and `j` are reduced to `len(s)` if they are greater. When `k` is negative, `i` and `j` are reduced to `len(s) - 1` if they are greater. If `i` or `j` are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of `k`). Note, `k` cannot be zero. If `k` is `None`, it is treated like `1`.

Comment: What does `None` mean here: `"foo"[None:None:-1]`? So the first None I assume means the last character in the string. Now what does the second None translate to?

Comment: Is the second `None` interpreted as  `-len(s) - 1`? `s` being the string in question.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi As noted: For a collection builtin `c`(and any object mimicking such), `None` as an `end` argument is interpreted as `len(s)`), The actual value passed to `__getitem__()` is still `None`. Note that slice ranges are end-exclusive.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. If the `end` argument is `-1` then what is the `start` argument? For reversing a string?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Sorry, typo, it's `len(s)` (-1 is `len(s) - 1`) of course. And `start` is `None`, which is interpreted as `0`.

Comment: What are are the **explicit** values used for `start` and `end` when the `step` is negative? Specifically for *strings*

Comment: The explicit values are `None`. Are you asking about the implicit values?

Comment: `end` is `len(s)` for a positive value of the step argument. I understand that. But what is it for a negative step? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Negative steppings cause `start` and `end` to flip. The gritty details are [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/143be366295038b36fc32c44b8e1b48a375eab56/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9239).

Comment: That doesn't make sense either because if they flipped then `"hello"[len("hello"):0:-1]` should be the same as `"hello"[::-1]`. Here `start` and `end` have "flipped" but the result is not the same.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Hrm, yeah. Read as "for the end value you always get one passed the end of the sequence, in whatever direction"

Comment: I mean I _intuitively_ understand what it does. Like I know what's happening here. But I want to know for certain what Python is using for the `end` argument as the default for a negative step. I just hate learning by just accepting something as that's how it "just works."

Comment: @AsadMoosvi And why don't you just go down into the implementation and check? Because the explanation for your initial question literally stops at "**it's up to the sliceable object to make sense of the default values.**".

Comment: I would've if I'd known C.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi The semantic explanation (added to the answer) isn't much better ;-)